# PHP: Object of class Closure could not be converted to int

Tags: php, arrays, closures, usort

I have a problem using the usort function. My array has the following model :

```
Fusion
|
| Array_1
| |
| | Array_1_1
| | | clock => "08:08"
| | | //Other fields
| | |
| |
| | Array_1_2
| | | clock => "04:51"
| | | //Other fields
| | | 
|
| Array_2
| ...
```

I want to sort the arrays in Array_X basing on the 'clock' field. I made this code, basing on the PHP documentation of [usort](http://php.net/manual/fr/function.usort.php) (4th example) :

```
foreach ($fusion as $fus){
    usort($fus,function ($key = 'clock'){
        return function ($a,$b) use ($key){
            return strnatcmp($a[$key],$b[$key]);
        };
    });
 }
```

... but it returns the following exception :

```
Object of class Closure could not be converted to int
```

Do you have any idea ? Thanks for your help.

Comment: What are you trying to do with that `function ($key = 'clock')`...?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You're trying to pass the following as a callback (2nd argument of usort)

```
function ($key = 'clock'){
        return function ($a,$b) use ($key){
            return strnatcmp($a[$key],$b[$key]);
        };
}
```

But the documentation clearly specifies that

> The comparison function must return an integer [...]

However, your callback returns another closure. This is why you get a Closure to int convertion Exception.

I believe what you're trying to do is to execute the inner-closure to get the final callback using the right values. I'd say this is useless because, unlike in Javascript, php closures are opt-in, not all-in, which means their context must be included with `use` the way you did for `$key` in the outer-closure.

You could simply do:

```
$key = 'clock';
foreach ($fusion as $fus){
    usort($fus,function ($a,$b) use ($key){
            return strnatcmp($a[$key],$b[$key]);
    });
}
```

And if `$key` comes from some other kind of context you may just have to adjust the variable assignment.

Comment: No more exception but the sort doesn't work. I'll try to find out why.

Comment: you mean, the results are not what you expect? Do you see any change in the array's ordering at least? Have you corroborated that `strnatcmp` works as you expect for times?

Comment: You're right, strnatcmp didn't returned what I expected. Now I convert my strings to DateFormat, it returns the right results, but still there's no change on my array. Here's my code : 

`foreach ($fusion as $fus){ 
    usort($fus, function ($a,$b) use ($key){ 
        $date1 = date_create_from_format('H:i',$a[$key]); 
        $date2 = date_create_from_format('H:i',$b[$key]); 
        return ($date1>$date2)?-1:1; 
    }); 
}`

E.g. : 
20:51 > 01:02 ? res=Yes 
08:53 > 20:51 ? res=No 
EDIT : how can I put linebreaks ?

Comment: It looks like changes in my array aren't registered. I'll create another post for this problem.

Answer (score -2):

Convert your object into an array using `get_object_vars($object)` first.

If the object that you are getting is generated by a different function, then read documentation for that function and find a way for it to return an array instead of object.

Examples and documentation can be found here http://php.net/manual/en/function.get-object-vars.php